# Active Admin and custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, activeadmin

This is my custom page in Active Admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Settings" do

  action_item do
     link_to('Import projects', 'settings/importprojects')
  end

  content do
    para "Text"
  end

  controller do
    def importprojects
      system "rake dataspider:import_projects_ninja"
      para "OK"
    end
  end

end
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I click on the button 'import projects', I want to preform a rake task with is in the controller. But I can't access the method.

What could be the problem or what I'm a doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, found it and here is the solution:

```
  sidebar :actions do
    button_to "Update projects", "/admin/projects/updateprojects", :method => :post, :confirm => "Are you sure?"
  end

  collection_action :updateprojects, :method => :post do
    system "rake dataspider:import_projects_ninja"
    redirect_to admin_projects_path, :notice => "Syncing..."  
  end
```

I created an button and it runs the method 'updateprojects'